# How to make a condition based on relation ship count in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to add a condition based on the `tasks` relationship count,

Here is the code:

```
return TeamleaderDeal
        ::withCount('tasks')
        ->get();
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
(...)
    "dealPhase": "Refused",
    "tasksCount": 5,
(...)
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
   (...)
    "tasksCount": 0,
    "companyLanguage": "nl",
(...)
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    (...)
    "dealPhase": "New",
    "tasksCount": 17,
    (...)
  },
  {
(...)
```

How to only return results where `tasksCount` equal to 5?

Comment: isn't simply using `where('taskscount', 5)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `has` method like this:

```php
// Retrieve all team-leader deals that have 5 tasks...
return TeamleaderDeal
            ::has('tasks', '=', 5)
            ->get();
```

Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) for more info.

Comment: Yes sure! I have one more question : 
How to add this condition as `OR` condition?

Comment: @MostafaAbdellaoui You may use `orHas('tasks', '=', 5)`.